# Xterm Set Title?

Tags: bash, xterm

I know i can set the title of Xterm using something like:

```
xterm -xrm 'XTerm.vt100.allowTitleOps: false' -T windowname
```

Is it possible to create this like a GUI, so Windowname is a prompt BOX. 
i.e. i click on Icon That when opens prompts me for a TEXT box window (GUI Not Terminal). 
I can then name the window prior to opening.

I can achieve this from a Bash script, But is it possible for a GUI method.
I work in a DE alot of the time and always launching multiple terminals. 
To be able to type a name prior to the Terminal box appearing is the solution am after.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This is a test program to set a name to Xterm per run

echo "Hello, "$USER".  This script is a test the set name in Xterm."

echo -n "Enter the title for your window and press [ENTER]: "
read name
echo

xterm -xrm 'XTerm.vt100.allowTitleOps: false' -T $name
```

Comment: Why does `allowTitleOps: false` enable being able to set the title? It looks like it should do the opposite!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a nice little tool called Zenity
This allows calling a GUI prompt box.

a Bash Script would look like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This is a test program to set a name to Xterm per run

echo "Hello, "$USER".  This script is a test the set name in Xterm."

XtermName=$(zenity --entry --text="Window Name")

xterm -xrm 'XTerm.vt100.allowTitleOps: false' -T $XtermName
```

The last 2 lines are only important.

## Creating a Variable to populate (User Input)

```
XtermName=$
```

## Created the GUI Input Box

```
zenity --entry --text="Window Name"
```

## Loads Xterm setting a title, the Title is varable $XtermName

```
xterm -xrm 'XTerm.vt100.allowTitleOps: false' -T $XtermName
```